# How do I make it so my discord bot will ask and answer in an order?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I am very new to coding, and am struggling to understand how I can make my discord bot (which I am creating through python) respond to different lines of code.

I have made an initial question and answer, however after that I cannot get the bot to respond to anything.

For example, my bot will respond correctly up until it is asked to Check / Back on the timetable area.

```
def setup():
    return "Hello! Welcome to the timetable bot. What service would you like? (Timetable / Subjects / 
    Homework)"
#End of setup

global userState

def overheard(message, user):
    if "Timetable" in message:
        return timetableenquiry()
    elif "Homework" in message:
        return homeworkenquiry()
    elif "Subjects" in message:
        return subjectsenquiry()
    return "I'm sorry I don't understand that."

def timetableenquiry():
    return ("Okay. What would you like to do with your timetable? (Check / Back)")

def timetablecheck():
    if "Check" in message:
        print("Okay. You can check your timetable at: www.timetableaccess.com")


def homeworkenquiry():
    return ("Okay. What would you like to know about your homework?")

def subjectsenquiry():
    return ("Okay. What would you like to do with your subjects?")
```

I appreciate any help and apologise if it isn't clear what I am asking.

Comment: Bit confused to what you are doing, a lot of the time you are returning a string when it looks like you need to print the statements like in timetablecheck? What's calling your functions?

Comment: If I was to use print instead of returning a string, how could I then go about writing more code and progressing with the conversation? I was under the impression that it would be easier for me to return a string and create the code on that, however I haven't been able to get that to work either.

Comment: So you'll have 'user input' and then a number of potential 'outputs'. Each string unless printed to the console will not be shown to the user unless there is some discord feature that is handling this? From looking on the internet quickly I can see this tutorial on how to create a discord bot. https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/ have you followed something similar? Seems there's more to it that just writing a console application.

Comment: Yes, I apologise, I have a set of client events which handle all of the interaction between the code and discord itself. My issue is the fact that I don't know enough about how write my code. I appreciate the help though, and I think I have a bit of a better understanding about going about my return and prints etc..

Answer (score 1):

You Should Use Message.Content to Detect it, You Also Want the Bot To Actually Type in the Discord CHANNEL. Also Try to Add a Prefix so the bot won't type randomly.

Take a Look a This:

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message): #Defines Message
  
  #If You Type TimeTable, And Role Requirement to Do So

  if message.content.startswith('-timetable'):
     await message.channel.send("Okay. What would you like to do with your timetable? (Check / Back)")
   
  elif message.content.startswith('-homework'):
     await message.channel.send("Okay. What would you like to know about your homework?")

  
  elif message.content.startswith('-subject'):
     await message.channel.send("Okay. What would you like to know about your subject?")

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN')) 
#Reminder: Put Your Token in a .env File and Write TOKEN=YOUR TOKEN.
```

EDIT: I FORGOT TO DEFINE CLIENT, try to use the updated one

Comment: Would this allow me to add more options and further conversations after the "await" statement? I have more options i'm looking to add, depending on what the user decides to do.

Comment: Please use the newer code, i didnt define client for the first one.

Comment: but yes, you can add much more to the await statement. but if you type -timetable, just give them the link. It will be much easier and you wouldn't need to add another check.